# How to gracefuly try to load packages in Lua?

Tags: lua, package

I would like to try to load a package in Lua.
The package is `ansicolors` and is only to have a better looking console output.

This is sugar and I don't want users to be forced to install this package.

So I tryed something like:

```
ansicolors = require 'ansicolors' or nil
```

But as I thought, it raise a module not found error and stops the execution.

So my question is: Is there a graceful solution to try to load packages and fallback on simpler solutions when it is not possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, the first version of my answer was incorrect - pcall returns module as its second value.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: It's OK I looked at the documentation. Even if they were a little mistake in the exemple it was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
local status, module = pcall(require, 'ansicolors')
ansicolors = status and module or nil
```

Comment: why have the 2nd line? just use: `local has_colors , ansicolors = pcall ( require , "ansicolors" )`

Comment: @daurnimator - because OP wants to get "module_value or nil" in just one variable.  Using two variables for the same functionality is a bit redundantly.