# Lua require works in Windows 7 but does not work with XP

Tags: lua

I'm requiring a module with the basic require:

```
  require "luatorrent"
```

and everything works just fine on 32 and 64 bit version of Windows 8/7/Vista but when the project is run on XP I get this error:

[image]

so the questions are:

A: Anyone have any idea why this issue seems to be XP specific even though its the very same Lua 5.1 and other files?

B: If this isn't something fixable without recompiling the module, that I cant do because its old and dont have the source, then can I somehow do the require then get a true/false if loaded so I can do a "if" statement to continue loading functions for the module as the error thrown breaks the code and the application wont continue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154740/how-to-gracefuly-try-to-load-packages-in-lua

Comment: lhf, thank you very much, that takes care of the running error but I know its a long shot as the module code is not available but do you have any ideas, however remote, as to why it just wont run on xp?

Comment: Why is the source code not available? Isn't it this: http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luatorrent/luatorrent/Version0.2 ?

Comment: dualed, thanks, I just picked up a compiled dll with a link to a now abandoned project site

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Lua Reference Manual entry on package.loaders](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders).

The first loader finds the DLL in your `package.path` and tries to load it as an DLL. It fails with the error message you see. Thus Lua usually goes on with the DLL loader, which looks for a DLL in [`package.cpath`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath). I guess your file is just not in the `cpath`. Alternatively, the DLL loader could be missing. Check if `#package.loaders != 4`.

For debugging, you could also try to load the DLL via the low-level [`package.loadlib`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loadlib) function (funcname should be `"luaopen_luatorrent"`).

Another reason, which comes to my mind is, that the DLL is 64 bit, but your XP 32 bit. But I think, in this case the error message would look different.

Comment: thanks Oberon, #package.loaders is indeed 4 and no error is thrown with: package.loadlib ('luatorrent', "luaopen_luatorrent")

Comment: If `#package.loaders` is 4, it is correct, so the DLL loader should be one of the four. So this should **not** be the cause of your problem. Check if the DLL is findable via `package.cpath`.

Comment: Hi there, package.cpath shows a load of pre defined locations including the root of the app, tried moving the dll to the other locations and the same thing happens, lfs and lanes work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help people, it turns out libeay32.dll needs to be either in system32 or the same folder as the module for this module to work.