# Lua - require fallback / error handling

Tags: lua, require, awesome-wm, luafilesystem

I'm currently using the `awesome` window manager on various Linux machines running different distributions.
All of the machines utilize the same (`lua`) configuration file.

Some of the machine have lua-filesystem (`lfs`) installed, while others don't.
My configuration would preferably use `lfs`, but if it is not installed I'd like to provide an alternative (suboptimal) fallback routine.

Here's my question in all of it's simplicity:

- How would I go about catching the error thrown by the `require(lfs)` statement?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15154740/1847592)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Any reason you didn't feel like voting to close as a duplicate?

Comment: I agree with the duplication vote. I'm just a bit chocked I couldn't find it searching, but at least other people will have this to find the answer as well now. - Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`require` is not a magical function. It's a function just like any other in Lua. And it signals errors using the standard error signaling facilities of Lua.

Therefore, you catch errors from `require` *exactly* like you do any other function in Lua. Namely, you wrap it in `pcall`:

```
local status, lfs = pcall(require, "lfs")
if(status) then
    --lfs exists, so use it.
end
```

Indeed, you can make your own `prequire` function that works for loading anything:

```
function prequire(...)
    local status, lib = pcall(require, ...)
    if(status) then return lib end
    --Library failed to load, so perhaps return `nil` or something?
    return nil
end

local lfs = prequire("lfs")

if(lfs) then
    --use lfs.
end
```